# Schedule Google Cloud Tasks to Invoke Firebase Function

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to setup a cloud task that calls a cloud function. I am able to setup the cloud task and I have setup some cloud functions, but I can't seem to get the cloud task to invoke the cloud function.

I am creating the task from my localhost by using this code

```
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccount.json');
const {CloudTasksClient} = require('@google-cloud/tasks');
const client = new CloudTasksClient({
    credentials: serviceAccount
});
const parent = client.queuePath("my-firebase-app-name-is-here", "us-central1", "matchmaking-queue-cleanup");
const task = {
    appEngineHttpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        relativeUri: '/leave-queue'
    },
};
task.appEngineHttpRequest.body = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify({
    id: "test"
})).toString('base64');
task.scheduleTime = {
    minutes: 13
};
const request = {parent, task};
client.createTask(request).then((response) => {
    console.log(`created task ${response.name}`);
}).catch(console.log);
```

This causes the task to show up in my console under cloud tasks.

[image: cloud tasks]

The task keeps failing and retrying. I don't see any logs from the cloud function side.

Here's what the cloud function looks like.
[image]

[image]

Any idea what I need to do to get the cloud task to invoke the cloud function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To trigger a Cloud Function you must use [HTTP targets](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks), not [App Engine targets](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-tasks). With App Engine targets the task is trying to find a special route to an App Engine application. You would change this in your task object:

```
const task = {
    httpRequest: {
        httpMethod: 'POST',
        url: <URL_FOR_FUNCTION>
    },
};
```

Here's a tutorial on how to use [Cloud Tasks with Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf).

Comment: I include the url as suggested here, and follow the service account section tutorial included in the link, but i still receive the status 'unavailable' when my task attempts to make the request to my fire base function. I am using the firebase-sdk for the onCreate to initiate the functions. could this be causing me issues?

Comment: Using `onCreate` creates a trigger for when new data is created in Realtime Database. To be invocable by a Cloud Tasks it needs to respond to HTTP requests; therefore you should use [`onRequest`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

Comment: to clarify, i have an onCreate function that is triggered once a new data object has been inserted into realtime database. The onCreate function schedules a task (successfully) the task makes an http POST to my onRequest function. Is audience required? I believe my oidc token address has the proper access.

Comment: To clarify you are not seeing the onRequest function being invoked at all? How are you creating your HTTP task?

Comment: The onRequest function is not being invoked at all. i create my task with.. await tasksClient.createTask({
        parent: queuePath,
        task,
      }). I see the task is created in my queue, but the response includes.. status: "UNAVAILABLE", and the function is never attempted to be invoked.

Comment: If i add allUsers as a member with invoker role to the function everything works as expected. if I remove allUsers and try to invoke with oidc token service account email which is a member on the function with invoker role it does not work.

Comment: said service account is Cloud Functions Invoker, Cloud Tasks Enqueuer, Service Account User. The service account is a member on the function as invoker, and member on the queue as task enqueuer

Comment: Thank you for these details. The minimal set of permissions needed should be: Create Task GCF Service account = Task Enqueuer and Service account user, while Service account added to task = GCF invoker. You should see the service account add to the token as an invoker of the accepting tasks GCF. You can also test out the service account invoking the function by setting it as your gcloud account, then curl the function url: curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)" URL

Comment: Lastly you could add `allAuthenticatedUsers` with role `invoker` to the accepting tasks GCF permissions.

Comment: The issue i was having was the my oidc token email address object was not properly nested in the task object

Answer (score -1):

Have you enabled the App Engine API ?
The Cloud Function needs this API enabled.